# How to gain write permissions to a remote Windows folder?

Tags: windows, permissions, shared-folders

I am running (L)Ubuntu 12.04 on this machine. I have a Windows folder (Windows XP box)  shared on the local network and can view the contents in PCManFM at smb://WindowsBox/ShareName (as shown in the address bar) and also at /home/me/.gvfs/sharename, and in Terminal at ./home/me/.gvfs/sharename

In Terminal, I can cp files to ./home/me/.gvfs/sharename but when I try copy/paste in PCManFM (drag and drop, etc.) nothing happens and no error message.

Of course I could stick to the CLI but it's a bit clunkier.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope opening PCManFM with root privileges would help you**

You can open it by executing this command in terminal:

```
sudo pcmanfm &
```

or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open launcher and write `gksu pcmanfm` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This would be more interactive.

Then go to destination where you want to read/write file. Hope you'd be easily drag/drop files/folder also.

Reply if something goes wrong.

Comment: As I understand one should use `gksu` instead of `sudo` for graphical stuff. Or you might get into trouble with your `~/.ICEauthority` file. Right?

Comment: @MadMike: Good that you asked this for confirmation :) One can use any way, it will work for both. Only difference in `gksu` is that it will ask your password in a good interactive GUI way. But `sudo` ask in the same terminal. I've edited my answer.. :)

Comment: `sudo pcmanfm &' returned `[1] 5489`. `gksu pcmanfm` asked for su password, then gave me a file manager window, but /home did not show the .gvfs folder to drill down into (all other hidden folders were visible), Go > Network Drives gave an "operation not supported" error.

Comment: @ThatJackElliott: `&` sign will send the process running at the back. So that your terminal would be used later. You've to give password in order to access the file. An of-course you've to go to your user actual user account in order to drill your files and folder. so if `jack` is your user account then you have to go to `/home/jack` and press then press **ctrl+h** to show hidden files and folder. Any file or folder name starts with **`.`** is hidden. So `.gvfs` would be hidden. :)

Comment: @SauravKumar: thanks, didn't know why it was suggested that I add the "&" to the command. Anyway, `sudo pcmanfm` opened the file manager, pointed to my /home/jack directory, and a box stating "Permission Denied."Clicking "OK" makes the error warning go away. It defaulted to showing the hidden ".name" files and folders, but as I said previously, .gvfs is not displayed. I toggled ctrl-h the display but .gvfs remains undisplayed.

Comment: @ThatJackElliott: can you see the file by simply opening it with any file manager..?

Comment: @SauravKumar: Well, I only have pcmanfm on this Lubuntu machine. It's unclear to me why pcmanfm would display the other hidden files but not .gvfs. Science is baffled!

Comment: @ThatJackElliott: So you're able to see `.gvfs` through terminal but not using any-other file manager!! Strange!! Try to install some other file manager like `thunar` or `nautilus` etc..

Comment: @SauravKumar: Yes, .gvfs is visible through Terminal. Looks like I have Nautilus already installed on this machine although it doesn't appear on any of the launcher menus. (Have to figure out how to get it to show, that's another thread.) Anyway, Nautilus does show .gvfs, but none of the directories in it that are visible with Terminal. According to Nautilus, .gvfs is empty.

Comment: @SauravKumar: Interesting . . . the icon that Nautilus chooses to show for /home/me/.gvfs is the File icon, not the Folder icon. And when do Go > Network, Nautilus says "Nautilus cannot handle `network' locations".

Comment: @SauravKumar: Thunar does go into the network and it finds the shared folders on the Windows machine. However, I don't have write privileges there -- Thunar says "permission denied." So I gotta give myself privileges there, which is where I started this thread.

Comment: SOLVED. I didn't have sharing set up properly on the Windows folder -- I needed to permit network users to change files. Duh.

Comment: @ThatJackElliott: Then mark this post as solved so that it will attract others attention and help them.

Comment: How do I mark it as solved?

Comment: @ThatJackElliott: Left to my answer you'll find a **tick** icon below to the votes up/down icons. You'll to click on the **tick** icon to mark it as solved. Hope you got it. :)